# Android change orientation of activity by sensor and button click

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to change orientation of my activity by sensor and also by action button click, but can't make it work together.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GraphActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_orientation:
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE )
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            else
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```